# How to effectively run Django with multi CPU cores

Tags: django, apache, performance, mod-wsgi, multicore

I'm developing a web application, and have a trouble that performance of Django doesn't improve when I increase number of CPU cores.
(actually 1 core does the highest performance and 2,4,8 cores don't differ much in their performance)
What my application does is to simply load static files(HTML, CSS, JS) and some data from database.
I use Apache as a web server and mod_wsgi.

Is this Django's normal behavior?
If so how could I improve the performance with multi cores?
(I want to increase number of cores because CPU usage reaches about 90% with just 1 core)

▼ab -n 200 -c 200  for 1CPU core and 1GB memory
[image]

▼ab -n 200 -c 200  for 2CPU cores and 1GB memory
[image]

▼vmstat 1  for 1CPU core and 1GB memory
[image]

▼vmstat 1  for 2CPU cores and 1GB memory
[image]

Comment: Django is built on top of Python and CPython has the GIL problem which causes this problem. Remember the following Django is a web framework and your biggest enemy is **IO** not **CPU**. **IO** can be *fixed* by using smart techniques AKA caching, optimized queries and memory data bases for Sessions.

Comment: No, Abdul is wrong. This has nothing to do with Django or Python, but is due to how you configure Apache

Comment: Daniel, you're right. I changed WSGIDaemonProcess localhost to WSGIDaemonProcess localhost processes=2 threads=25, then performance got much better.

Answer (score 15):

I found that I just had to make some changes to Apache config file.
I changed

```
WSGIDaemonProcess localhost
```

to

```
WSGIDaemonProcess localhost processes=2 threads=25
```

then response time decreased from 7 seconds to 2 seconds.
after that, I experimented with other number of CPU cores, and when I set the same number of processes as number of CPU cores, performance got better.

Comment: This helped me more than anything! Thanks!

Comment: This saved me a lot of time - Thank yu!